# How to scheduled a job on an Oracle standby database

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Can anybody tell me how to schedule a job on a standby database using dbms_scheduler? The following PLSQL works on the primary but doesn't work on the standby. It schedules a job to drop a restore point.

```
DECLARE
    rp_drop_time DATE;

BEGIN
    SELECT to_date(to_char(next_working_day, 'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 19:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') rp_drop
    INTO rp_drop_time
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'D') IN (5,6) THEN next_day(sysdate, 'Monday')
            ELSE sysdate + 1 END next_working_day
            FROM dual
    );

    dbms_scheduler.create_job
    ( job_name => 'RP0567901235'
    , job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
    , job_action => 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''DROP RESTORE POINT "RP0567901235"''; END;'
    , number_of_arguments => 0
    , start_date => rp_drop_time
    , enabled => TRUE
    );
END;
/
```

Comment: Is this job actually needed? In a physical standby scenario won't the delete job get propagated to the standby DB from the primary in the normal way? And if the restore point name is the same as the one on the primary, then won't it also get deleted automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to schedule a job on a physical standby DB as it's in mount mode (normally). Use an alternative method to drop a GRP at a future date - like a cronjob, 'at' cmd, OEM Job etc.